# Is Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) supported on Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is [Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx) supported on [Microsoft Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/)?

Comment: I just asked this question, and found it here -- the question both old and new and the answers are crisp.  Did the 'closers' check with someone who is familiar with Microsoft sql servers?  Can they ask now and unclose the question?

Answer (score 9):

MARS (Multiple Active Results Sets) has been [available on SQL Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/04/16/9997517.aspx) since 16 Apr 2010.

Answer (score 3):

Not currently. [See here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlnativeclient/archive/2010/02/12/using-sql-server-client-apis-with-sql-azure-vversion-1-0.aspx).

Comment: On March 19, the SQL Azure team announced April availability. So while technically not currently available, it will be in the next month.

Answer (score 3):

MARS will be available in April. This was just announced on Friday. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlazure/archive/2010/03/19/9981936.aspx) from the SQL Azure blog for more details.